# ListBoxItem with modified background can't indicate whether its selected?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

on a ListBox's DrawItem event, I set the background color of each ListBoxItem like so:

```
g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.LightYellow), e.Bounds);
```

The only problem I'm having now, is after I change the background color, I can't tell when a ListBoxItem with a modified background color is selected.  In other words, after a ListBoxItem has a modified background color, when I try to select it, its background color doesn't change to blue to indicated it is selected.

How can I have my cake and eat it too, by having my ListBoxItems with modified backgrounds indicate whether they are selected or not too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be inspecting the `State` member of the `DrawItemEventArgs` parameter to your handler to determine whether or not the item is selected (or focused, etc.) and then draw the background as you see fit.

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.drawitemstate.aspx) has a good example of how to do that.

Comment: Initially, nothing is selected.  At this point, this is where certain ListBoxItem backgrounds are changed.  After this initialization, I want to be able to select any ListBoxItem in my ListBox and clearly see it is selected when it has an initially modified background color.

Comment: Right, but `DrawItem` will be called when an item becomes selected as well. At that point, since you've gone the OwnerDraw route, it is up to *you* to actually draw in a selection rectangle (whatever you'd like that to look like.) Inspecting `State` will tell you which elements of your item should be drawn (selection rectangle, focus rectangle, disabled text, etc.)

Comment: Ah, that clears things up a lot, thanks for explaining that to me.

Comment: Simplest way is `if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected) { ... }`. `DrawItemState` is a `[Flags]` enumeration, so you have to test for individual bit values.

Comment: Ah, I was doing e.State == DrawItemState.Selected, and that alone wasn't working. Thanks much for the help! :)